# Cannot SCP into Oracle VM, SSH is working

Tags: networking, server, ssh, windows, scp

I have an Oracle OCI instance with Ubuntu running and I'm trying to upload my website into it.
I've enabled HTTP connections and everything seems to be working fine (I can see my index html page under /var/www/html and I can access it by inputing the instance public ip in the browser)

I've saved my public and private ssh keys when I created my instance and I can connect to it via ssh from CMD from windows (I am using windows to connect to this OCI ubuntu instance).

So, this command works fine, I am able to connect:

```
C:\Users\andrei\Desktop> ssh -i website/ssh-key-2022-08-25.key ubuntu@193.122.2.213
```

However, I want to transfer my whole website from my local computer under `C:/wamp64/www` to my Ubuntu server under OCI.. And somehow it doesn't work.

This is the command I'm using and isn't working:

```
C:\Users\andrei\Desktop>scp prod.rar -i website/ssh-key-2022-08-25.key ubuntu@193.122.2.213:/home/ubuntu
ubuntu@193.122.2.213: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

I tried with WINSCP and also with SCP command from windows terminal, and nothing works, having this error:

```
ubuntu@193.122.2.213: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection.
```

I have 2 key files (one private, one public - .key and .key.pub). When I inputed the private one into WINSCP it generated me a .ppk file and if I input this file into Putty->Connection->SSH->Auth , putty is working. However, If i input this file into WINSCP, it is not working.

It is failing with:

```
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "ubuntu".
Server refused our key.
Authentication failed.
```

Basically ssh is working with the key, but scp is not.

I also have the Ingress Rules from OCI set up and accepting the ports 22,80,3306 etc from any source (0.0.0.0/0).

Here is the WINSCP log:

```
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.555 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.580 Looking up host "193.122.2.213" for SSH connection
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.580 Connecting to 193.122.2.213 port 22
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.639 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.19.6
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.654 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.654 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.654 Have a known host key of type ssh-ed25519
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.701 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.802 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 host key, but we don't know it
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.802 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.802 ssh-ed25519 255 ad:82:3a:1e:bc:f6:10:df:cd:05:00:55:ba:e2:96:98 20P3/JDC3v/ziBMXtkq+AU4T377feHIHTHcb6AmFqL4=
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.825 Host key matches cached key
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.825 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.825 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.826 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.826 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.857 Reading key file "C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\website\ssh-key-2022-08-25.ppk"
! 2022-08-25 14:31:09.858 Using username "ubuntu".
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.909 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.909 Offered public key
! 2022-08-25 14:31:09.947 Server refused our key
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 Server refused our key
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
* 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
. 2022-08-25 14:31:09.994 Closing connection.
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 (EFatal) No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 Authentication log (see session log for details):
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 Using username "ubuntu".
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 Server refused our key.
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 
* 2022-08-25 14:31:10.018 Authentication failed.
```

What can I do?

I've just created another instance but this time on Oracle Linux, not Ubuntu, and SCP is working, along with ssh, without any other modifications. Just created it, inputed the key and it is working. What can I do for it to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried Putty's file browser? What was the command you used for SCP from the terminal?

Comment: This is the command from the terminal to scp: scp prod.rar -i ssh-key-2022-08-25.key ubuntu@193.122.2.213:/home/ubuntu. I don't know what you mean by Putty's file browser and what to do with it.

Comment: For scp, all options have to come before the source and target arguments. The way you have written it, `scp` will just treat `-i` and `ssh-key-2022-08-25.key` as source arguments, not as options.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same thing and in my case updating winscp to the latest version(currently 5.21.3) solved it.
SSH Bug: https://winscp.net/tracker/1952

Comment: When someone reads this 2 years from now latest version may not be the same. Exact version is required to make this a good answer.